# How to say "here you go" when giving a gift?

Tags: translation, mandarin

I believe you can informally say "gěi" when handing something over like the soy sauce during dinner, right?

But what can you say when you give a gift? Like "Here you go" instead of just "Here". Or maybe "This is for you". Something simple and short, please. :)

Comment: Something simple and short, then `这是(送)给你的。`

Comment: If someone gave me a gift and just said "Here you go" I would think they were trying to make it seem routine, or unimportant.  Do you mean to suggest that?

Comment: Colin, well no, not really, but a) Chinese don't like to open or look at presents in front of you, and b) I don't know enough Mandarin to have a proper conversation but I'd still like to say -something- when handing over the gift. ^_^ songyuanyao, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are handing over a gift:

- 送给你。("A gift for you."), or
- 给你。 ("For you."), or
- 这是给你的。("This is for you.")

You can expand it, like:

- 这是给你的...。 ("This is a/some ... for you."), or
- 这本书是送给你的。("This book is a gift for you.")

Don't forget that in some cases, you have to use 您 instead of 你.

You can make it more polite by saying: 请收下 ("Please accept it.") or if you are accepting a gift and your partner makes some polite comment about the gift and/or the occasion you can say: "谢谢，我收下了。" ("Thank you, I accept it.")

Comment: 谢谢^^ Very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, please consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: I tried, but it says I need a reputation of 15 to vote it up. :S Edit: Oooh. Okay, is it accepted now? Wrong button I think.

Answer (score 0):

I most often hear people say 送你 in Taiwan when they give presents, not sure if mainland would be different though.